# Simple issue - Make a second UL column to display next to the first one

Tags: html, css

I created an unordered list and separated its elements in two different classes: x1 and x2.

I want to website to display the elements of the second column (x2) at the same height than the first one and also next to it (just like text columns in an old book).

So far I've tried this on my CSS with no success:

- .x2 {margin-bottom:12px;}
- display:inline-flex

Any ideas?

```css
 
 .x1 {
    -webkit-columns: 100px 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 1; /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 1;
}

 .x2 {
    -webkit-columns: 100px 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 1; /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 1;
 margin-left:100px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="x1">a</li>
<li class="x1">b</li>
<li class="x1">c</li>
<li class="x1">d</li>
<li class="x1">e</li>
<li class="x1">f</li>
<li class="x1">g</li>
<li class="x1">h</li>
<li class="x1">i</li>
<li class="x1">j</li>
<li class="x1">k</li>


<li class="x2">l</li>
<li class="x2">m</li>
<li class="x2">n</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: So why dont you split this into 2 lists and have them side by side, each one in it's own div?

Comment: Because on the real website I'm building, the UL element is tied to a javascript function that I got from github. If I split the UL in two lists, the javascript stops working :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plunker Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/szaSnoBNyTa0JPCG5Iwh?p=preview

```
HTML
<ul>
<div class='container' ><li class="x1">a</li>
<li class="x1">b</li>
<li class="x1">c</li>
<li class="x1">d</li>
<li class="x1">e</li>
<li class="x1">f</li>
<li class="x1">g</li>
<li class="x1">h</li>
<li class="x1">i</li>
<li class="x1">j</li>
<li class="x1">k</li></div>

<div class='container' >

<li class="x2">l</li>
<li class="x2">m</li>
<li class="x2">n</li>
</div>
</ul>

css

 .x1 {
    -webkit-columns: 100px 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 1; /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 1;
    clear:right;
}

 .x2 {
    -webkit-columns: 100px 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 1; /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 1;
    margin-left:100px;
    clear:right;
  }

  .container
  { float:left; width:auto;}
```

Comment: I thought you did not want to mess with the structure of the ul element because of javascript limitations. That's what you replied to my comment. Apparently throwing 2 separate divs in there like I suggested is the accepted answer... My answer uses just a ul element like you requested

Comment: @DimitrisCSD Splitting the list in two by making two or more `<ul>` lists is different than using `<div>` elements inside a single `<ul>`, that's why your suggestion doesn't work and this one does. Your suggestion changes the semantic meaning and _literally_ creates two lists, while the `<div>` method doesn't change the semantic meaning and allows for _visual_ splitting of a single semantic list.

Comment: And what about the answer that doesn't use 2 divs or 2 uls, as requested?

Answer (score 0):

**Reading "left > right > down" solution:**

You can force the the li elements to only have 50% width and then this should split them into 2 columns.

```
ul {
  width: 500px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

#twoCols li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Reducing that width of each list item will allow this to have more than 2 columns. For example if you're aiming for 3 columns 33% would do it.

Check out my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m35o8o9q/

**Reading "top > down > right" solution**

You can also achieve this with a different order of reading with using some other css:

```
#twoCols {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 60px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 60px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 60px;
}
```

Of course changing the column count number will result in more columns if required.

Here is a fiddle of this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/yn3m5vnc/